# Powershell Custom Prompt Adds a Zero at the End

Tags: powershell, prompt

I've been experimenting with creating my own Powerline-inspired custom prompt for Powershell.

I have created the `Prompt` function in my `$PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts` file as such:

```
using namespace System.IO
using namespace System.Collections

function Prompt() {

    class PromptBlock {
        [string]       $Contents
        [ConsoleColor] $Fore
        [ConsoleColor] $Back

        PromptBlock([string]$str, [ConsoleColor]$fg, [ConsoleColor] $bg) {
            $this.Contents = $str
            $this.Fore = $fg
            $this.Back = $bg
        }
    }

    $Characters = [PSCustomObject]@{
        ZWNJ = "$([char]0x200C)"
        NBSP = "$([char]0x00A0)"
    }

    $PLGlyphs = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Branch  = "$([char]0xE0A0)" #  Version control branch
        LN      = "$([char]0xE0A1)" #  LN (line) symbol
        Padlock = "$([char]0xE0A2)" #  Closed padlock
        RArrow  = "$([char]0xE0B0)" #  Rightwards black arrowhead
        WRArrow = "$([char]0xE0B1)" #  Rightwards arrowhead
        LArrow  = "$([char]0xE0B2)" #  Leftwards black arrowhead
        WLArrow = "$([char]0xE0B3)" #  Leftwards arrowhead
    }

    function Print([string]$str, [ConsoleColor]$fo, [ConsoleColor]$bg) {
        Write-Host $str -ForegroundColor $fo -BackgroundColor $bg -NoNewline
    }

    function Section([ConsoleColor]$from, [ConsoleColor]$to = [ConsoleColor]::Black) {
        Print "$($PLGlyphs.RArrow)" $from $to
    }

    # Prints the user name, white on blue
    $CurrentUserName = ((Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty username) -split '\\' )[1]
    
    # Current Path
    $CurrPath = $PWD.Path

    $Blocks = [ArrayList]::new()

    $Blocks.Add([PromptBlock]::new($CurrentUserName, [ConsoleColor]::White, [ConsoleColor]::DarkBlue))
    $Blocks.Add([PromptBlock]::new($CurrPath, [ConsoleColor]::Black, [ConsoleColor]::Green))

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Blocks.Count; $i++) {
        $CurrentBlock = $Blocks[$i]
        $NextBlock = $Blocks[$i + 1]
        $NextBlockColor = $NextBlock.Back
        if (-not $NextBlockColor) {
             $NextBlockColor = [ConsoleColor]::Black
        }

        Print " $($CurrentBlock.Contents) " $CurrentBlock.Fore $CurrentBlock.Back
        Section $CurrentBlock.Back $NextBlockColor
    }

    return "$($Characters.NBSP)"
}
```

But the result of this prompt displays as the following in Windows Terminal, and by extensions in the "old timey" Powershell console.

[image: Mysterious Zero]

I have absolutely no idea where the zero comes from and why the code doesn't reach the `return` statement.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. No zero shows up in my PowerShell (5.1), only the special glyphs are missing in the default font.

Answer (score 1):

The zero comes from the first `$Blocks.Add(...)` statement.

Suppress the output from `ArrayList.Add()` and it'll work:

```
[void]$Blocks.Add([PromptBlock]::new($CurrentUserName, [ConsoleColor]::White, [ConsoleColor]::DarkBlue))
[void]$Blocks.Add([PromptBlock]::new($CurrPath, [ConsoleColor]::Black, [ConsoleColor]::Green))
```

Or use a collection type that doesn't return anything when you invoke `Add()`:

```
$Blocks = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PromptBlock]]::new()
```